# How to write startup.nsh for linux kernel boot?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, uefi

How to write startup.nsh for linux kernel boot?
Thank you for answers!

Comment: For example, https://github.com/andy-shev/buildroot/blob/intel/board/intel/common/post-image.d/90-create-disk-image#L255

Comment: This is not an how to, where to learn or any description. But let me ask you what does it mean to use syslinux in the script?

Comment: `syslinux` is not related to your original question. Are you asking (another question) why we are using it? That entire script is to create a bootable image of a Buildroot distribution for any type of the (x86) boot system: legacy BIOS, UEFI (with or without EFI Shell), in UEFI case we simply provide `startup.nsh` and we build kernel with EFI stub.

Comment: Not another  question, I was concerned about the connection of syslinux with the starup.nsh. End else, a good answer. Then I can learn from you?

Comment: You can learn from the code :-) Ask questions on this site as usual and somebody (maybe even me) will probably react on.

Comment: Why is their no open teaching on the subject of a startup.nsh? It is in my term a kind if knowing that the intel community is a part of that power to the people. But in searching for a description and explenation of the architecture, their is no invitation in the clear aspects for discovering the possibilities availible and also realistic to implement. May it be that I ask at the wrong end, but do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Windows 10 machine and your startup file system is the same as mine use the following, else you might have to change:

This line goes into the startup.nsh file at the same location (fs0:\efi\boot) :

```
fs0:\efi\boot\bootx64.efi
```

If you just have the efi shell then type:

```
help -b
```

for all commands

or proceed to edit the startup.nsh
either:

```
edit fs0:\efi\boot\startup.nsh
```

or:

```
fs0:
cd efi
cd boot
edit startup.nsh
```

or:

```
fs0:
cd efi\boot
edit startup.nsh
```

Add the startup.nsh line above and you're golden.

It definitely works but if you can't find the efi\boot folders on `fs0:` then you might want to check all the file systems displayed at the start before the UEFI boot tries to read the startup.nsh that might not exist.